# Can I prevent a method called by another method from being called without changing the definition of the original method?

Tags: python

In OpenAI's Gymnasium environments, there's a `render()` method that at the end calls `pygame.display.flip()` to draw on the screen. I'm trying to prevent the `render()` method from calling the `pygame.display.flip()` method without changing the definition of the `render()` method. Is that possible in any way?

Comment: The short answer is "no".  But you have the source, so just copy it into your own subclass.

Comment: @TimRoberts the problem is that each environment has a different `render()` method so I have to change the source for all of them and provide the changed source which is not something ideal. Is it really impossible to do that?

Comment: The equally short answer is "sure" by redefining `pygame.display.flip` to a def that does nothing, then restoring it afterwards. `render` will still _call_ it, but it won't do anything.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's an interesting suggestion, I wasn't thinking in terms of the other library. I'll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is for testing environment, then you might be able to use unittest.mock.patch to disable the call.

If you want to do this is a production code things gets a bit more tricky, but since it's open source, what you can do is just build your own version of the library.

It is possible to use unittest.mock for monkey patching outside the context of unit tests, it's not very recommendable, but if you know what you're doing, we're all consenting adults here.

Comment: It's not really meant for production but I wouldn't say it's really testing. Essentially if I was to build my own source I have provide a copy of the Gymnasium module and I'm not sure if that's a good idea. Wouldn't it be better if others can just use the default version?

Comment: Why is monkey patching not recommended for outside of the context of unit tests?

Comment: Monkey patching means you're breaking the API contract. It can be done if you know what you're doing and under the right conditions can be done, but it can be brittle if the library changes its internal implementation or if there are multiple libraries that are doing monkey patching all doing so in slightly incompatible ways. If you take the risks into account, you think it's still better than the alternative, then you can do so if you wish. But it should only be done as a last resort.